# Not able to download a playlist using youtube-dl which has a removed video in my ubuntu 16.4

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, youtube-dl

I am new to linux system, i was just finding a way to download whole playlist at the same time, i found youtube-dl could work for me, but whenever i try to download a playlist from youtube which has a removed or deleted videos youtube-dl just stops downloading instead of skipping it. Please help if possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

youtube-dl has a lot of powerful options. Run `youtube-dl --help` (or look [at the documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options)) to see them. Among them is:

```
-i, --ignore-errors     Continue on download errors, for example to
                        skip unavailable videos in a playlist
```